# cannot subscript a value type of '[Int]'

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to query a parse table for a number and place it within a label in the cell. But when I try to assign the value from parse into the value in the label in the cell I receive an error of cannot subscript a value type of '[Int]'

here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let singleCell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell


    singleCell.Name.text = Label[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.entryNumber.text = runnerNumber[indexPath.row]


    return singleCell


}
```

it is with the entryNumber code line that I received the error: cannot subscript a value type of '[Int]'
I googled but did not find anything of a similar circumstance 
Any advice?
I am using Parse as my backend, swift, and Xcode 7

Comment: and what is `Label` and `runnerNumber`? Show how they're defined and setup

Comment: @IBOutlet var entryNumber: UILabel!
   runnerNumber = [Int()]

Comment: Try using `singleCell.entryNumber.text = "\(runnerNumber[indexPath.row])"`

Comment: Thanks that worked Russel

Answer (score 0):

From @russell

`singleCell.entryNumber.text = "\(runnerNumber[indexPath.row])"`